# Trying to draw a vertical shape with a loop

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have been trying to create 8086 asm code to print vertical, green stripe in the middle of the screen.
I can not understand, why this loop does not work properly:

```
    mov BX, 5 
loopbegin:
    push BX

    MOV AH,02H

    MOV BH,00H 

    MOV DH,00H      

    MOV DL,022h      

    INT 10H        

    MOV AH,09H

    MOV AL,00100000b

    MOV BH,00H

    MOV BL,0a0h

    MOV CX,01H

    INT 10H

    pop BX
    dec BX

    jge loopbegin       


    mov AX, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

Comment: Since you set the cursor to the same position every time, what do you expect to happen? You might want to try using your loop counter.

Comment: Sorry for being so dull. Just have seen that...

Comment: Still fighting this issue, how to manipulate the increase of DH?

Comment: For example, `mov dh, bl`.

Comment: Dear Jester, could you please add some explanation, becasue I want to learn something useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, `dh` is the row number so moving `bl` which is your loop counter into it will draw into different rows. In your example that would be counting down from 5 so drawing upwards.